# Read csv file content and pass into json array to post via HTTP Post Action - Microsoft Flows

Tags: scheduled-tasks, power-automate

I am trying to read the contents of a csv file that looks like the example below, and then pass the values as json in the body of an HTTP Post action to an API from Microsoft Flows.

```
id, firstname, lastname, email, createdate

1, joe, smoe, joesmoe@joe.com,7/31/2018

2, jill, smoe, jillsmoe@jill.com, 7/31/2018
```

I am able to read the File contents using the SFTP connector,
The problem I am having is converting the content to JSON

I need the output that I pass to the API to look like this

```
    [
      {    
      "properties": [
        {
          "property": "firstname",
          "value": "joe"
      },
      {
        "property": "lastname",
        "value": "smoe"
      },
      {
        "property": "email",
        "value": "joesmoe@joe.com"
      },
      {
        "property": "createdate",
        "value": "7/31/2018"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to convert to JSON, you can construct it in your own way.

I would just you to put that CSV content in String array, like the firstline in 0 and 1,2 and so on.

Use the **compose** shape of Flow to construct the message, per your requirement you can construct the string like below :-

***stringArray** is where your CSV content is split into string array. 
stringArray can be assigned inside the loop with index.

```
[
      {    
      "properties": [
        {
          "property": "firstname",
          "value": "stringArray.split(',')[1]"
          },
      {
        "property": "lastname",
        "value": "stringArray.split(',')[2]"
      },
      {
        "property": "email",
        "value": "stringArray.split(',')[3]"
      },
      {
        "property": "createdate",
        "value": "stringArray.split(',')[4]"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```